# How do you craft armor in Final Fantasy XIV?

Tags: final-fantasy-14

I am currently in open beta in FFXIV with a character that is an Archer and I also have the items for an Armor crafter. How do you actually make things, or how do you find recipes for items to actually make items? I cant figure out what I need to start leveling this profession or how to find the materials/recipes I need to create items.

If there is anyone else that is in the beta that could help me out, it would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question refers to the 1.0 version of Final Fantasy XIV, and neither the question nor any of the answers are even remotely valid in FFXIV: ARR.

Comment: How did this even get bumped?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you do the local leve quests for your craft. The quest provides you with all the needed materials and by the time you finish, you will have a good understanding of how crafting works. Just accept a local leve that is lvl 1. Start synthesis and click requested button on the synthesis menu. Then select your leve quest and commence.

Answer (score 2):

Get yourself a whethered doming hammer, then do as Jon suggested.  Doming hammer is the primary Armorworker's tool.  Check out http://www.eorzeapedia.com 's wiki for a good breakdown of recipies.

Comment: If they're an archer, they're going to need the leatherworker and weaver's tools -- armorsmith mostly does heavy armor, which the archer can't wear.